# Not able to send cookies using `fetch` in NextJS server side component (app router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am working on a NextJS project using app router. I have created an API and I now have to consume it in the fronted in a server side component.

I am getting an error that says: `JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided`

Here's my server side component:

```js
const getData = async (slug: string) => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/users/user", {
        method: "POST",

        body: JSON.stringify({ username: slug }),
        credentials: "include",
    });
    console.log("this is after the api call");

    const data = await response.json();

    if (!data) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch /api/users/user API");
    }
    console.log(data);

    return data;
};

const Page = async ({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) => {
    const data = await getData(params.slug);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Page: {params.slug}</h1>
            <p>{data.username}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

Here's my API call:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

import authData from "@/lib/authData";

const POST = async (request: NextRequest) => {
    try {
        const reqBody = await request.json();
        const { username } = reqBody;
        if (!username) {
            return NextResponse.json(
                { message: "No username recieved!" },
                { status: 400 }
            );
        }

        const data = authData(request);
        if (!data) {
            return NextResponse.json({
                isLoggedIn: false,
                isSelf: false,
            });
        }

        if (data.username === username) {
            return NextResponse.json({
                isLoggedIn: true,
                isSelf: true,
            });
        } else {
            return NextResponse.json({
                isLoggedIn: true,
                isSelf: false,
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json(
            {
                message: error.message,
            },
            {
                status: 500,
            }
        );
    }
};

export { POST };
```

and here's my authData function:

```
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const authData = (req: NextRequest) => {
    try {
        const token = req.cookies.get("token")?.value || "";
        console.log("token: ", token);

        const data: any = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET!);

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Invalid Token: " + error);
    }
};

export default authData;
```

Things I have tried:

- I was originally trying to do the same using Axios but was getting some error
- I tried calling the same API using Insomnia (it's like Postman) and it works absolutely fine.

After reading the error, I feel I am doing something wrong with the fetch request and token is not being sent to the server for that.

Other than that, I was originally using just the route to the server API as `/api/users/user` rather than stating whole route like `http://localhost:3000/api/users/user`

How do I fix this?